# C# BindingSource Filter with space in between

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I want to filter data in a binding source through user input by a text box. The filter can contain white spaces. So for example my binding source contains:

```
Hi There
Hi Where
Hi Care
```

and if the user enters **Hi T** I only want to show the first result.

Here is how I set my biding source filter:

```
_dataSource.Filter = "Name like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";
```

where **txtSearch** contains the input string. I found that the filter simply ignores anything entered after space.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem based on the current post.  Your filter works for me when I enter "Hi T".

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue. Rename the Column with a word that has a underscore instead of a space example

`Name_Like`  instead of `Name Like` .

That solved the issue for me.

Comment: Or you can suround the word with [] brackets if you want to keep the space